# Invalid format for date labels in graph

Tags: stata

I'm only starting with Stata but went through a lot of available pages already to find answer to this.

Using simple dataset with two variables  `aa` and `bb`.

aa is formatted as `%td`
bb is formatted as `%8.0g`

The graph command I've been using is as follows:

```
graph twoway tsline bb, 
title("Numbers by Day", size(medsmall)) 
ytitle("Value", size(small)) 
xtitle("Date", size(small)) 
ysize(2) 
xsize(4) 
tlabel(#15, labsize(vsmall), format(%tcD_m_CY)) 
ylabel(#10, labsize(vsmall))
```

I am trying to format dates as something else rather than `21jan2016`

but whatever I put in the `format` function I get an error "Invalid Date"

`%tcD_m_CY` is just an example from Stata forum: I tried double quotes and other things and it all fails..

(I did use `tsset` first to define date axis.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lacks a minimal, complete, verifiable example in so far as (1) it lacks data we can read in and (2) several details in your example are irrelevant to your problem.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Your example shows an argument fed to the `format()` suboption of `tlabel()` (**not** function) which starts `%tc`: this insists to Stata that values which have been input as daily dates (and counted as # days with an origin 0 = 1 January 1960) are to be interpreted as date-times (and counted as # milliseconds with origin 0 = 01jan1960 00:00:00).

So, by your instruction, a daily date such as 25 July 2016 (which is held as 20660 given that origin) is to be displayed as if it were a date-time. Such a date-time is just about 2 seconds after the start of 1 January 1960; and the rest of your display format `D_m_CY` says "just show me day, month and year" and the day, month and year are, as said, 1 January 1960 according to this instruction.

I see nothing invalid in your date format so far as Stata is concerned; the problem is human, that it is not at all what you want. Naturally, I can't explain exactly what was wrong with whatever other code you tried and don't show us.

The fake data and code below illustrate some technique. For daily dates, labelling every day is usually a bad idea with more than about a week's worth of data, as you just don't have enough space; similarly showing the same year again and again is usually unnecessary and a poor use of space. An axis title such as "Date" is superfluous so long as dates are clearly given. These points apply whatever software you are using.

```
clear 
set obs 15 
gen aa = daily("30 Jun 2016", "DMY") + _n 
format aa %td 
mat bb = (12, 14, 10, 8, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25) 
gen bb = bb[1, _n] 
tsset aa 

graph twoway tsline bb, /// 
title("Numbers by Day") ytitle("Value") xtitle("") /// 
tlabel(#7, format(%tdd_M))
```

[image]

It's your graph, but the bottom line is simple: daily dates will need some kind of `%td` format, and `%tc` format is utterly wrong, on a par with confusing cents and millions of dollars as units.

You don't say exactly what you read, but this is well documented: `help datetime` in Stata and whatever it points to are all you need to study.

Note also http://www.statalist.org/forums/help#spelling

Comment: Thanks, I will improve the quality of next questions and provide some example data etc. 

While using your example I realised what was the issue, there should be no comma between labsize and format suboptions - those are separated by space.